# One custom maintenance page for all errors (Nginx)

Tags: nginx, maintenance, custom-errors

I want to show `one custom maintenance page` for `all errors`. What code should I put to my nginx setting below? and the file of my nginx setting is located at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name myip;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://myapp:8000;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias   /myapp/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /myapp/media/;
    }
}
```

And this is my `maintenance.html` file below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Site Maintenance</title>
<style>
  body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; }
  h1 { font-size: 50px; }
  body { font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; }
  article { display: block; text-align: left; width: 650px; margin: 0 auto; }
  a { color: #dc8100; text-decoration: none; }
  a:hover { color: #333; text-decoration: none; }
</style>

<article>
    <h1>We&rsquo;ll be back soon!</h1>
    <div>
        <p>Sorry for the inconvenience. We&rsquo;re performing some maintenance at the moment.</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

My `maintenance.html` looks like this on browsers.

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your `maintenance.html` file at `/var/www/html/maintenance.html`.
2. Put the `error_page line` and `location block` showing below.

---

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name myip;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://myapp:8000;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias   /myapp/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /myapp/media/;
    }

    ##### Put this code #####

    error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 421 422 423 424 425 426 428 429 431 451 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 510 511 /maintenance.html;

    location = /maintenance.html {
        internal;
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    ##########################
}
```

---

I referred to [this website](https://blog.adriaan.io/one-nginx-error-page-to-rule-them-all.html) to solve your problem. [The website](https://blog.adriaan.io/one-nginx-error-page-to-rule-them-all.html) teaches how to show one custom error page for all errors. I also referred to [this website](https://www.calazan.com/how-to-configure-nginx-so-you-can-quickly-put-your-website-into-maintenance-mode/) to get the code of maintenance.html.